# How to speed up Connections to specific websites during peak times

Tags: networking, performance, website

There is a website I use for work that at a specific time loads some information that I need but since everyone is checking at that exact moment their servers slow down. I was told there are ways to increase load times by using barebones firefox and not loading ads but is there anything else I can do to decrease my load time? Someone even told me it may be possible to "cut in front of the line" so to speak and have my request answered first. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: In order to "cut in line" you'd need some sort of QoS set up, but that would be done at the router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll want to reduce the time your browser takes to load the site, possibly by disabling anything you don't need, such as browser plugins, javascript, image loading, etc.

Assuming your own system is fast enough to deal with all this or you've disabled everything possible, then you can't actually do that much.

If your own internet connection is the bottleneck, then try plugging in a LAN cable, using a less heavily used network, or upgrading your plan with the ISP.

Otherwise, if the bottleneck is indeed with the site's servers there isn't actually much you can do besides help them out. Since you use the site so regularly consider donating to/paying the owners, so they can upgrade their servers. Given the dough they'll probably be grateful and more than willing to help you out here.

Comment: Thanks. I wish I could but they are actually a huge company that have been contracted by my employer to do this. If I could throw them some extra money I would. Thanks for your input.